# Setting CustomButtonField as Background in black berry

Tags: blackberry

can any one tell me how to set custom button field as background in black berry.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a ButtonField as a background. If you are just trying to use an image check out the  BackgroundFactory class. Also be aware that setting the background on a MainScreen typically doesn't work -- you'll have to set a background for a VerticalFieldManager and then add that to the Screen.